# How can I configure Nginx to route a specific request pattern to a specific php-fpm upstream hosting a Symfony application?

Tags: php, symfony, nginx, routes, microservices

I'm developing an **application composed of 3 microservices**. Each microservice is a **Symfony 4 application**.

To route all my request made to this application I'm using **Nginx**.

There are, for now, three url patterns, one for each microservice. One of them is the `^/auth` pattern which allow the access to the authentication API through the php-fpm upstream.

I've tried many things but for now this is the closest Nginx configuration I have from my objective.

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name app.local;
    root /app;

    # location directive for the authentication API
    location ~ ^/auth/ {

        root /app/public;

        fastcgi_pass auth_api_upstream;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/auth)(/.*)$;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root/index.php$fastcgi_path_info;

        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # ....

    # return 404 if other location do not match
    location / {
        return 404;
    }
}
```

With this configuration, this is what append :

- I make a request : *GET /auth/publicKey*
- Nginx handle the request : *GET /auth/publicKey* and forward it to my application through the upstream
- The Symfony application handle the request : *GET /auth* instead of *GET /publicKey* (my objective)

While Nginx is handling the request :

- $realpath_root = '/app/public' : Where the Symfony entrypoint is on the php-fpm host
- $fastcgi_path_info = '/publicKey' : A valid route url in the Symfony application

**So my questions are :**

- Why is my application handling a GET /auth request when the request previously handled by Nginx is GET /auth/publicKey ?
- And therefor, how to fix it ?

Thank you for your answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to move the `include fastcgi_params;` line upward

something like this:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name app.local;
    root /app;

    location ~ ^/auth/ {

        root /app/public;

        set $app_entrypoint /index.php;

        fastcgi_pass auth_api_upstream;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/auth)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $document_root;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_URI $app_entrypoint;

        fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $fastcgi_path_info;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $app_entrypoint;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$app_entrypoint;

    }

    # return 404 if other location do not match
    location / {
        return 404;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hum it works now, thank you but... `include fastcgi_params;` isn't just a flag ?